# Multiple Ajax function calls cause slow to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
    function function1(val)
    {
       $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'page1.php',
         data: {
           get_option:val
         },
         success: function (response) {
           document.getElementById("id1").value=response; 
           function2(val);
           function3(val);
           function4(val);
           function5(val);
         }
       });
    }

function function2(val)
    {
       $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'page2.php',
         data: {
           get_option:val
         },
         success: function (response) {
           document.getElementById("id2").value=response; 
           function6(val);

         }
       });
    }

function function3(val)
    {
       $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'page3.php',
         data: {
           get_option:val
         },
         success: function (response) {
           document.getElementById("id3").value=response; 

         }
       });
    }
```

This is my some functions function1 success part I call other functions like function2, function3, function4, function5. In my Second function function2 I call another one function function6 on its success part its more time to get its results
**How to avoid this wait time...?**

Comment: A) Get a faster server, or B) change your logic so you don't throw around so many requests

Comment: How to avoid many requests. But I get Correct results in my all functions

Comment: @Sambhu try to return all the data in one ajax call. You can make changes in service layer.There must be separate methods which are handling those requests. Instead of separate methods for each ajax call write one method and if there are for dao calls , call all doa in that single method. Then create json object and store all the values in it.Return that json

Answer (score 0):

If each of your ajax requests are returning results somewhat sequentially it's probably session blocking in effect. If the execution of the scripts can be performed simultaneously without affecting the results, try adding the following early in the PHP code:

```
session_write_close();  //let the next requests start
```

This will allow the subsequent ajax requests to begin PHP processing and should improve your results significantly.